# A function to automate the classification of value ranges

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How could I classify this data according to [these criteria](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNkkb.png)?

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Af | Class |
| 2 | 73.73 |  |
| 3 | 68.10 |  |
| 4 | 39.69 |  |
| 5 | 50.51 |  |
| 6 | 18.23 |  |

| Class | Range |
| --- | --- |
| Class 1 | Af < 21 or 68 <= Af |
| Class 2 | 21 <= Af < 42 or 55 <= Af < 68 |
| Class 3 | 42 <= Af < 55 |

I've tried using `IF` `OR` but without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The criteria can be simplified:

```
if 42 <= Af < 55:
    Class 3
else if 21 <= Af < 68:
    Class 2
else:
    Class 1
```

This can be expressed in a formula, formatted to match the layout of the pseudocode:

```
=IF(AND(42 <= @A:A, @A:A < 55),
    "Class 3",
 IF(AND(21 <= @A:A, @A:A < 68),
    "Class 2",
    "Class 1"
))
```

Or in a single line:

```
=IF(AND(42 <= @A:A, @A:A < 55),"Class 3", IF(AND(21 <= @A:A, @A:A < 68), "Class 2", "Class 1"))
```